# Set property value like part of another property in YAML config spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, yaml, spring-config

I have YAMl config file with property:

```
send-executor:
    thread-max-count: 5
```

And I have another property:

```
ready-query: SELECT * From ...(another conditions).. where ROWNUM >= 5
```

Can I set instead **5** in `ROWNUM >= 5` my another property `thread-max-count`?

Somthing like this:

```
ready-query: SELECT * From ...(another conditions).. where ROWNUM >= {$thread-max-count}
```

Or I need set placeholder and change it in java code only?

Comment: You can use @Value("${thread-max-count}") and then use that variable in query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can. Ths syntax is `${send-executor.thread-max-count}`